# MySQL Server Split Scaling Databases/Tables among Users

Tags: mysql, scalability

I'm relatively new to Databases and have been looking into a solution that will allow users, under my server, to access their own data and no one else. I want these databases for the user to be scalable, so if more space is needed to store files, they can do so with little intervention.

I was looking into MySQL, as I have only done single database work with it, and was trying to see how this could potentially be done. Would the best course of action be set a database for each user? That way the tables for each database are separate, password protected, and cannot exchange data among the tables in other databases? I know there can be essentially unlimited databases and tables, in addition to table sharding/partitioning, so I think this is a solid choice, but was wondering if anyone who has worked with MySQL more had any input.

Thanks

EDIT: Update for clarification of desires. So what I essentially want is a platform where I am the owner, but I can have users log in to my platform to access their data. This data will probably mostly include files, such as PDF's, but as to their size I cannot tell, but am planning for the worst. They will be able to use a web/application to view their files and download, upload, sort, delete these files. So in addition to creating files, there will be the ability to see historic files and download those as well if desired. What my platform will be providing is the framework for these files with fields being autofilled if I can, as well as the UI for the file management. My concern comes from architecture of having multiple users, with separate data, to be kept separate, scalable, and not completely crash the server with read/writes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to store the users "files" as BLOBs in the database which doesn't necessarily lend itself to scaling well in the first place.  Depending on the type of files generally the best solution would be to provide security in the application layer and use cloud based storage for your files.  If you need an additional layer of security (i.e. users can only access the files assigned to them) there are a number of options - one such option, for example, assuming you were using S3 would be to use IAM profiles which could be generated when the user a/c is set up.  The same would apply for any third party cloud storage with API.

Having an individual database per user would be an administrative nightmare unless you could generate each database on login (which would mean a separate data store for credentials anyway so it would be somewhat pointless) and also would not work in a BLOB storage scenario.

If you can detail a little more in terms of precisely what you are trying to achieve and why there will for sure be plenty of answers.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes I believe you are correct, I plan to store these files as PDF's and such, so them keeping their raw data will be useful. I realize this is pretty bad for scaling as well, why I have been quite puzzled about how to accomplish this. I was looking at AWS as well, but I did not think of splitting S3 buckets among IAM profiles, which would handle the protected data aspect quite well actually.